# Irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ and tensor product decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $\pi_n$ be the irreduicble representations of $SU(2)$. Let $n\geq m $
I want to show that $\pi_m \otimes \pi_n =\pi_{n+m}\oplus\pi_{n+m-2}\ldots \pi_{n-m} $.

I know that $\chi_{\pi_n}=\frac{\sin(n-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}$. In generally for characters we have 
$\chi_{\rho \otimes \pi}=\chi_\rho \chi_\pi$ and for a compact group 
$\pi \sim \bigoplus_{\rho\in \hat{G}}\left\langle \chi_\pi,\chi_\rho\right\rangle\rho$ where $\hat{G}$ is the irreducible representations of $G$.

This gives that $\pi_m \otimes \pi_n=\bigoplus_{\rho\in \hat{G}}\left\langle \chi_\rho,\chi_{\pi_m}\chi_{\pi_m}\right\rangle\rho=\bigoplus_{\rho\in \hat{G}}\left\langle \chi_\rho,\frac{\sin(m-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\frac{\sin(n-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\right\rangle\rho$.

I think its also true that the only irreducible representations in $SU(2)$ are $\pi_n$. Which gives $\bigoplus_{j\in \mathbb N}\left\langle \frac{\sin(j-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)},\frac{\sin(m-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\frac{\sin(n-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\right\rangle\pi_j$.

I do not know how to calculate $\left\langle \frac{\sin(j-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)},\frac{\sin(m-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\frac{\sin(n-1)\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\right\rangle$, and i'm not actually sure how to define the inner product.

Update: Another approach I have been trying is that two representations are isomorphic if and only if their characters are the same.
The character of $\pi_{n+m}\oplus\pi_{n+m-2}\ldots \pi_{n-m} $ is given by $\chi_{\pi_{n+m}}+\chi_{\pi_{n+m-1}}+...\chi_{\pi_{n-m}}$. The character of $\chi_{\pi_n\otimes \pi_m}=\chi_{\pi_n}\chi_{\pi_m}$. But I am having trouble showing these are equall.

Comment: The decomposition of $\pi_m\otimes\pi_n$ is known as the Clebsch-Gordan formula. We have surely covered it. I think there was a recent answer by Lord Shark. Gimme a moment.

Comment: It is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3384483/11619). Have you covered the theory of weights and formal characters yet? If not, then the discussion there may not be very useful to you :-(

Comment: Actually, you can make use of the result from [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3437212/11619):
$$\chi_{\pi_n}=\sum_{k=0}^ne^{i(n-2k)\phi}.$$
Multiply the two characters in this form. You get a double sum. Then do the same for the sum of characters of $\pi_{n+m},\pi_{n+m-2},\ldots,\pi_{n-m}$. Voila! That's actually what Lord Shark is doing in that other thread, but in different language.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks I'll try that